# Providing Tomcat JVM options in ARest server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, cookies, jvm

I want to provide "-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE=true" to my Tomcat jvm options so that HttpServletRequest cookies can be parsed even if "=" is present in cookies. I have tried couple of options below -

1 - Specified it in TomcatJvmOptions opconfig.

2 - Added below lines in server target

```
<jvmarg value="-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE=true" />
 <jvmarg value="-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0_COOKIE_READS=true" />
```

3 - Added below lines in server target

```
<sysproperty key="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE" value="true"/>
<sysproperty key="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0_COOKIE_READS" value="true"/>
```

4 - Added below lines in build.xml

> value="-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0_COOKIE_READS=true"/>

None of the above methods have worked. Can you please guide if I'm making some mistake?

Thanks.